# Will my hair grow back?

Tags: removal, scar-tissue-scars, hairloss, cysts

I have three cysts in my scalp and they cause me headaches.  I plan to remove them however, I'm afraid about not having my hair grow back.  How likely is it that I might have permanent bald spots as a result of these cysts?